# is this sentence correct 会議は三時からでいらっしゃいます.?

Tags: honorifics

会議は三時からでいらっしゃいます.
(I'm studying the honorific and humble forms)
Thank you

Comment: Answers will differ depending on what you are trying to say.  Is someone going to a meeting?  Or do you want to say that there is a meeting at 3:00?  Your current sentence makes no sense as-is.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is incorrect. いらっしゃる is a honorific form of 「行く」「来る」「居る」「ある」「いる」. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/15386/meaning/m0u/

会議は三時からです is polite and 会議は三時からでございます is more polite.

Answer (score 1):

If a secretary tells her boss “会議は三時からでいらっしゃいます,” he’ll roll eyeballs and laugh away. “いらっしゃいます” is an honorific to mean ‘be’ or ‘come / go,’ as Yuuich suggested. For examples:

ご主人はお元気でいらっしゃいますか ‐ Is your husband in good shape?

あの方は雲の上の人でいらっしゃる – He is a man above the cloud, meaning out of one’s reach.

どちら様でいらっしゃいますか？- May I ask what's your name?

会長は３時頃いらっしゃいます - The Chairman will be (come) here around 3 o’clock.

どちらへいらっしゃいますか？－Where are you going?

You’d better say simply ”会議は三時からです,” or ” 会議は三時から始まります - The meeting will start from 3:00 pm.”.