# Can a sonkeigo verb be used with an inanimate subject? / 尊敬語は無生物主語に対して使えますか？

Tags: honorifics

As a background, consider this question: “[is this sentence correct 会議は三時からでいらっしゃいます.?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30456)”

My initial thought was like this:

> A sonkeigo (尊敬語) verb is used to show the speaker’s respect toward the subject of the verb.  Therefore, 会議は三時からでいらっしゃいます would show the respect toward the meeting, which is nonsensical because the meeting is not a living thing.

But then I started to wonder if a sonkeigo verb can ever be used with an inanimate subject.  [敬語の指針 (2007)](http://keigo.bunka.go.jp/guide.pdf) does not seem to mention cases like this.  After some trial and error, I came up with a sentence 先生のご活躍は多岐にわたっていらっしゃいます.  This sentence sounds maybe OK to me, but I am not sure and I would probably say 先生は多岐にわたって活躍されています instead.

To summarize, my questions are:

1. Is 先生のご活躍は多岐にわたっていらっしゃいます correct?
2. If not, can a sonkeigo verb be ever used with an inanimate subject?

## 和訳

話の流れとして、「[is this sentence correct 会議は三時からでいらっしゃいます.?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30456)」の質問のことを考えます。

私は当初こういうふうに考えていました。

> 動詞の尊敬語はその動詞の主語に対する話者の敬意を示す。したがって、「会議は三時からでいらっしゃいます」というのは会議に敬意を示すことになり、会議は生き物ではないので意味が通じない。

しかし後になって、無生物にも尊敬語が使える例はないだろうかと思い、[敬語の指針 (2007)](http://keigo.bunka.go.jp/guide.pdf) を見たところ、このような用例には言及していないようでした。考えぬいたあげく、「先生のご活躍は多岐にわたっていらっしゃいます」という文を思いつきました。これなら個人的にはまあそんなに間違ってはいないかなという気もしますが、自分だったら「先生は多岐にわたって活躍されています」と言うと思います。

以上を踏まえて質問です。

1. 「先生のご活躍は多岐にわたっていらっしゃいます」は正しい文ですか？
2. 正しくないとしたら、動詞の尊敬語は無生物主語に対しても使えますか？

Answer (score 4):

「先生のご活躍は多岐にわたっていらっしゃいます」 seems OK. Consider these other examples:

- 「先生のご出身は東京でいらっしゃいます」
- 「先生のご指摘はごもっともでいらっしゃいます」
- 「社長の方針は内製化でいらっしゃいます」
- 「先生の演説は素敵でいらっしゃいました」

While these are odd:

- 「先生の車はベンツでいらっしゃいます」
- 「先生のネクタイは素敵でいらっしゃいます」

Assuming my judgments are correct, I think the important part is how representative the noun is of the honorable person. Someone's origin, opinion, plan, or speech is representative of them as a person, while someone's car or necktie is not.

Also, there is this sentence:

- 「先生の演説は三時からでいらっしゃいます」

I think this one is pretty unclear. While on one hand it's referring to the honorable person's speech (like before), the speech hasn't actually happened yet, so it's more referring to *an event* than the speech contents, so I think いらっしゃいます can possibly seem weird here.

Answer (score 1):

I think sentence 1 and 先生は多岐にわたって活躍されています are correct.

In addition, I think, as you said, sonkeigo(尊敬語) and kenjyougo(謙譲語) aren't basically used with inanimate subject but used with actions and teineigo(丁寧語) is used with them like "です、ます".

Comment: Because 先生のご活躍 is inanimate, I think that the first paragraph and the second paragraph of your answer are contradicting each other….

Comment: In addition, http://careerpark.jp/34368

Comment: > *"Dictionary said 敬語 are used with actions"* - what exactly does that mean?

Comment: 社長のネクタイは、素敵でいらっしゃいますね is unnatural but 社長は、素敵なネクタイをしていらっしゃいますね is natural. 
This sonkeigo is used with the action which chief executive wear a nice tie.

Comment: 「先生のご活躍は多岐に渉っていらっしゃる」is absolutely and logically incorrect. But  「先生は多岐にわたって活躍されていらっしゃる」is logically and rhetrically corect..

Comment: Why is 「先生のご活躍は多岐に渉っていらっしゃる」 incorrect?

Comment: Reread my answer well. You need not to use honorific words to abstract objects such as honesty, knowledge, activity and inanimate objects and animals like monkey, snake, and centipede. You can  use it for 先生、but not 活躍。You'd better rephrase it as 先生は（実に）多岐に渉って活躍されている。It's not an issue of trope. It's the issue of logic, which applies to Japanese, English language and any languages.

Comment: 活躍 is action. It is different from inanimate objects like a desk.  honorific can be used for the action of the objects. So I think 先生のご活躍は多岐に渉っていらっしゃる isn't odd.

Comment: Of course 活躍 is action. So nothing wrong with saying （先生は）活躍されている。[活躍]は多岐に渉る is OK. But 「活躍」は多岐に渉っていらっしゃる is really odd and awful whether it' modified by 先生の or not.

Comment: 先生の活躍は多岐に渡っている is OK, isn't it? So when いる change to honorific, It become 先生の活躍は多岐に渡っていらっしゃる。However I don't deny you feel it odd because the affection is different with each other.

Answer (score 1):

先生のご活躍は多岐に渡っていらっしゃる sounds correct to me.

If a word can be the subject of an honorific verb depends on if the word has sense of animacy. 先生の活躍 is something that can influence people. That's why it can be the subject, I believe. On the other hand, 会議 is not the case unless it stands for a kind of personification of some organization.

Edit: I'm wondering that the reason why 会議は三時からでいらっしゃいます sounds odd is that the verb is a form of いる, and how 会議は３時からで あらせられます would sound.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, it’s illogical to use honorific verbs for inanimate objects in Japanese as it is so in English.

I’ll be stunned if I hear some examples given by other user:「先生のご指摘はごもっともでいらっしゃいます」「社長の方針は内製化でいらっしゃいます」「先生の演説は素敵でいらっしゃいました」. They're terrible. They're  not Japanese at all, at least not proper Japanese.

先生 can be “お元気でいらっしゃる” and "ご多忙でいらっしゃる", but “ご活躍 - activity” can not be “多岐に渡っていらっしゃる” even if it’s preceded by “先生の.” So,“先生は多岐に渡ってご活躍されています” would be a logical and proper way of saying.

But this rule – Impropriety of using 敬語 for inanimate object including abstract nouns such as activity, study, knowledge and objects like desk, pen, TV set, car, and animals such as dog, elephant and monkey is often overlooked and violated in today’s conversation.

先生のご活躍は多岐に渡っていらっしゃる sounds awkward and odd to me, though some of you might overlook its illogicality and take it for granted. If I should pick up better one from two evils, I would pick up ”先生のご活躍は多岐に渡っておられる” rather than ”先生のご活躍は多岐に渡っていらっしゃる.”

Comment: I think ”先生のご活躍は多岐に渡っていらっしゃる.” isn't incorrect. 先生の活躍　is action, so to use honorific for it isn't odd. I asked some people about this, they say it isn't incorrect.

Comment: I said 'some of you might overlook its illogicality and take it for granted' upfront. But they don't know to whom (not what things) 敬語 should be used. It' illogical..

Comment: Yes. 敬語 isn't used for the thing but person and their actions.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe the language is changing in front of us. Do you @YoichiOishi think 先生のご活躍 wrong by itself?

Comment: @broccoli forest. Nothing wrong with 先生のご活躍。I'm saying「ご"活躍" - as the subject - は（が）多岐に渉って"いらっしゃる"」is a terrible abuse of Japanese 敬語 -honorific expression.

Comment: @YoichiOishi My personal sense suggests that the honorability is transferable from 先生 to 先生のご活躍, thus it can trigger honorification of the predicate (unlike 先生のお車 etc.; I basically agree with Darius Jahandarie's answer). Do you think people of your generation generally frown on this usage (for I think you are my senior by far)?

Comment: I'm 83 years old. We were rigorously told how to use 敬語 in  schoolhood. But I don't know how today's young people use it loosely. But isn't it funny to hear 先生のお車はお綺麗でいらっしゃる。We call such turn of phrase 歯が浮く，of which literal translation is your teeth start to waggle because of its weirdness.

Comment: Continued: For the record, "歯が浮く" is used basically for flattering, for example 葉が浮くようなお世辞。 Again, we don't say 陛下の馬は白であらせられ、速くお走りになられる。