# いらっしゃいます and なさる difference

Tags: honorifics

I know, that both are honorifics, but I thought that いらっしゃいます is more often used when expressing state-of-beeing, aka "Is Tanaka-sama here?" and なさる when expressing doing: "Can someone do it?".I can vaguely guess that いらっしゃい is more polite and can be added with ~te, but I come often to see that in above situation both words can be used.How can I differentiate them between one another?

Comment: One verb is "to be", the other one "to do". You are asking a question: *How can I differentiate [] between ["to be" and "to do"]?* -- I don't understand it. They look different and they sound different. That's how you differentiate them.

Comment: @macraf -- "Do Be Do Be Do." -- Frank Sinatra 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are honorific forms of different verbs, and the degree of respect is not relevant.

いらっしゃる is an honorific version of いる, くる and (で)ある/だ.

> - 先生は部屋にいます。 → 先生は部屋にいらっしゃいます。
>     Sensei is in the room.
> - 社長は今日ここに来ます。 → 社長は今日ここにいらっしゃいます。
>     President will come here today.
> - この方は王女です。 → この方は王女でいらっしゃいます。
>     This person is a princess.
>     <sub>(This cannot be used with inanimate objects. これはリンゴでいらっしゃいます is incorrect.)</sub>

なさる is an honorific version of する and やる.

> - どうしますか？ → どうなさいますか？
>     What would you do?
> - 社長は今日ここを訪問します。 → 社長は今日ここを訪問なさいます。
>     President will visit here today.

Comment: (It’s very much an advanced point, but IMO いらっしゃる can be used with inanimate objects in limited cases, see https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30646/3097)

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Ah, yes, thank you for pointing it out.